# How to integrate Magento 2 in BPM/camunda engine

Tags: magento2, bpmn, camunda

I am new in **BPM/camunda engine.**  I need to know How to integrate **Magento2** in BPMN 2.0.

I searched about BPMN 2.0 https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/bpmn20/project-setup/ its only setup java project.

Magento 2 need  php and web servers(apache, nginx) support,  see this link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

How can I setup magento 2 in Camunda-bpm tool?  Suggest me any way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

please see your answer here https://forum.camunda.org/t/how-to-integrate-magento-2-in-bpmn-2-0/1777/2

> Camunda is running inside a java web container or application server, while Magento is using php. Which means that best you can get is running 2 servers, one with camunda and second one with Magento. Those servers may communicate with eachother using external Task and REST services.